# is there an any way to discard '\n'?

Tags: c, string, buffer

I am trying to to record response by the user(using `getchar()`). I am having issues with `'\n'` sticking in buffer. If I use `fgets(char* buf, .. , ..)`, `'\n'` again goes into `buf` and you have to include `'\n'` at the end of the test string. when using string.h functions (like `strcmp()`). Is there any clean way of writing code for such purposes.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    int main()
    {
    char buf[100];
    fgets(buf, 3, stdin);
    puts(buf);
    int i = strcmp("p\n", buf);
    printf("%d", i);
    //if (!strcmp("CLock to random\n", buf))
    //{
    //puts("sucess");
    //}
    char c;
    c = getchar();
    putchar(c);
    return 0;
    }
```

Now I want to record response(single character  'p'). If I use getchar(), in place of fgets(), program skips second getchar()( c = '\n'). If I use the current code, i have to include \n in strcmp() every time.

Comment: with getchar() you can check your input against `\n`, ..put your code here so that you can find Better answer.

Comment: Now do you want to discard or include the `\n`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to discard the `\n`:

```
char buf[0x1000];
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
char *p = strchr(buf, '\n');
if (p) *p = 0;
```

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan No. Why use `scanf()` when you can use `fgets()`? Also, why do you assume this solution is incorrect?

Comment: It's an integer, expressed in base 16 (i.e. in hexadecimal).

Comment: @H2CO3 no your solution is good, but I wanted to combine all yours three steps. ..anyways OP got the answer. that is good..

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* chomp(char* str){
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    if(len>0 && str[len-1] == '\n')
        str[len-1] = '\0';
    return str;
}

int main(void){
    char buf[128];

    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
    printf("<%s>\n", buf);  //include newline
    printf("<%s>\n", chomp(buf));//drop tail newline
    printf("<%s>\n", chomp(buf));//NC

   return 0;
}
```